# Paginate in query

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

I have inserted a join query in Orders controller like this:

```
def index
  @orders = Order.joins(:user)
           .select("users.id AS user_id,users.first_name,users.last_name,users.email,orders.amount,orders.description,orders.created_at")
  @count = 0
  render :layout => 'orders_layout'
end
```

How do I paginate the above query?

Answer (score 3):

[will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) and [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) are good options. Kaminari also supports mongoid.

[Will paginate railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate) and [Kaminari railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari) is a good starting point.

Comment: Yup it works through this :@orders = Order.joins(:user).select("users.first_name,users.last_name,orders.amount,orders.description,orders.created_at").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)........I'm new to rails : )

Comment: You should use kaminari. I myself try it and recommend for everyone :)
Some another gem like rails_admin or active_admin, also use kaminari for paginate. So if your site use rails_admin it included kaminari, and you don't need to include another paginate gem, nice!.

Comment: Add will_paginate gem and add this to your query `paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)`